# Fast and efficient way to get a Dictionary "key" based its "values" which is an array of Strings in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, performance, dictionary

I am programming in Swift and have a Dictionary like below which maps a company's employees to their department:

```
var acmeInc: [String: [String]] = [
    
    "marketing"  : ["john", "amanda", "peter"],
    "operations" : ["anna", "teresa", "jack", "tom", "nigel", "katy"],
    "sales"      : ["bill", "jill"]
]
```

I want to create a function which will return the department of the employee. So the function takes in an employee name and returns the department they work for. What would be the fastest and most efficient way of doing this? Or should not even use a Dictionary in the first place and use some other data structure?

```
func printDepartmentOfEmployee(employee: String)
{
  ...   
  
  print("\(employee) works in department \(...)")
}
```

The simplest "brute-force" method I can think of is to have a large dictionary mapping each employee to each department, but wanted to see if there was a better way of doing this.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Lookup by key is fast. Lookup by value is nonexistent. So using a dictionary keyed by department was silly to begin with, if knowing a department based on a name was what was important to you. Start over and reassess your needs.

Comment: The issue is that there are many employees but very few departments, so that is why I thought of using this structure. Perhaps using a dictionary is not the correct data structure.

Comment: I don't believe there's anyway around a 'Brute' search. The only thing I can think of is to avoid having to create another dictionary. You could loop over the keys in a dictionary, search that array for that key and keep going until you find the person.

Comment: This would mean you wouldn't have to make a 'duplicate' of the information you already have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't said anything about where you think you're going with this. But in general, put your trust in *objects*. Use structs, not dictionaries, and try not to use hard-coded strings unless you have to — for instance, if a limited number of department types is known, use an enum. Here's an example:

```
enum Department {
    case marketing, operations, sales
}
struct Employee {
    let name: String
    let department: Department
}
struct Corporation {
    var employees = [Employee]()
}
```

Here's how we'd construct the "same" data you're using in your example:

```
let employees : [Employee] = [
    .init(name: "john", department: .marketing),
    .init(name: "amanda", department: .marketing),
    .init(name: "peter", department: .marketing),
    .init(name: "anna", department: .operations),
    .init(name: "teresa", department: .operations),
    .init(name: "jack", department: .operations),
    .init(name: "tom", department: .operations),
    .init(name: "nigel", department: .operations),
    .init(name: "katy", department: .operations),
    .init(name: "bill", department: .sales),
    .init(name: "jill", department: .sales),
]
var acme = Corporation()
acme.employees = employees
```

Think about the advantages of this arrangement. Given an employee, we now know that employee's department *instantly* — it is the employee's `department`.

If you really need to look up the department corresponding to an employee name, that's easy too. Similarly, if you need the employees in a department. We just give the Corporation some simple methods for doing those things:

```
extension Corporation {
    func departmentOfEmployee(named name: String) -> Department? {
        employees.first(where: {$0.name == name})?.department
    }
    func employeesInDepartment(_ department: Department) -> [Employee] {
        employees.filter {$0.department == department}
    }
}
```